# Getting a specific object from a group of object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In a gridlist,I want to get only specific objects in an array.Here is my code.

```
$scope.incIncObj = [];
$scope.gridList = {};
$scope.gridList.incIncObj = studyValue.incluExcluCriteria;
console.log(studyValue.incluExcluCriteria);
```

In c#,the datas are like this,

```
var incluExcluCriteria = (from IE in _context.Incl_Excl_Criteria
                                      where IE.Study_ID == request.Study_Id
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          IE.Incl_Excl_Id,
                                          IE.Study_ID,
                                          IE.Criteria_Type,
                                          IE.Criteria
                                      }).ToList();
```

In the console,I am getting all the list such as,

```
[Object { Incl_Excl_Id=2992, Study_ID=350, Criteria_Type="I", more...}, 
Object { Incl_Excl_Id=2993, Study_ID=350, Criteria_Type="E", more...},
Object { Incl_Excl_Id=2994, Study_ID=350, Criteria_Type="I", more...},
Object { Incl_Excl_Id=2995, Study_ID=350, Criteria_Type="E", more...}, 
Object { Incl_Excl_Id=2996, Study_ID=350, Criteria_Type="I", more...},
Object { Incl_Excl_Id=2997, Study_ID=350, Criteria_Type="I", more...}, 
Object { Incl_Excl_Id=2998, Study_ID=350, Criteria_Type="E", more...}, 
Object { Incl_Excl_Id=2999, Study_ID=350, Criteria_Type="E", more...}]
```

But I want to get only the object which has Criteria_Type="I" like this,

```
[Object { Incl_Excl_Id=2992, Study_ID=350, Criteria_Type="I", more...}, 
Object { Incl_Excl_Id=2994, Study_ID=350, Criteria_Type="I", more...}, 
Object { Incl_Excl_Id=2996, Study_ID=350, Criteria_Type="I", more...},
Object { Incl_Excl_Id=2997, Study_ID=350, Criteria_Type="I", more...}]
```

Give me any suggestion

Comment: Use filter to filter only Criteria_Type="I"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use javascript `filter` prototype method to filter the array

```
$scope.gridList.incIncObj = studyValue.incluExcluCriteria.filter(function(obj){
   return obj.Criteria_Type ==="I"
})
console.log(studyValue.incluExcluCriteria);
```

note that your json is invalid. use colon instead of `=` when you are assign value to property

this  `{ Incl_Excl_Id=2992, Study_ID=350, Criteria_Type="I"}` should be change

to this `{ Incl_Excl_Id:2992, Study_ID:350, Criteria_Type:"I"}`

```js
var studyValue = [{ Incl_Excl_Id:2992, Study_ID:350, Criteria_Type:"T"}, { Incl_Excl_Id:2992, Study_ID:350, Criteria_Type:"I"}, { Incl_Excl_Id:2992, Study_ID:350, Criteria_Type:"S"}, { Incl_Excl_Id:2992, Study_ID:350, Criteria_Type:"I"}, { Incl_Excl_Id:2992, Study_ID:350, Criteria_Type:"I"}, { Incl_Excl_Id:2992, Study_ID:350, Criteria_Type:"K"}, { Incl_Excl_Id:2992, Study_ID:350, Criteria_Type:"I"}, { Incl_Excl_Id:2992, Study_ID:350, Criteria_Type:"I"} ]

 var incIncObj = studyValue.filter(function(obj){
       return obj.Criteria_Type ==="I"
    })
    console.log(incIncObj);
```

Comment: @Vidhyasagar Vasis no prob. if this helped make sure to vate and mark as answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Why to write custom filter ? This code may not work in code snippet.But try this pipe filter in your application.I just tried myself and gives you the short & easy answer for your query.

```html
 <div ng-repeat="c in collection | filter : 'I'">
      <span>{{ c.Incl_Excl_Id}}</span>
      <span>{{c.Study_ID}}</span>
      <span> {{c.Criteria_Type }}</span>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another angualrjs approach would be using the filter provided by angular.

First inject `$filter` service in your controller. Then use it like below-

```
var filteredList = $filter('filter')(youFullList, {Criteria_Type:"I"})
```

for more details- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter